# Is it possible to use MiracleCast with Miracast over Infrastructure (MICE)

Tags: wireless, display, ethernet, wifi-direct

I can't find any proper documentation about MiracleCast supporting `Miracast over Infrastructure (MICE)` 
and I was wondering if its possible to use MICE with MiracleCast somehow or I just have to use something like https://github.com/homeworkc/lazycast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per github issue #400

https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues/400

There is no support for "miracast over infrastructure" (MS-MICE) yet on miracle cast.

I'm using lazycast on raspberry pi it works great except for one visual bug.

I know of no other miracast sink that supports miracast over IP/ethernet (and not, currently the windows implementation still requires the sink to advertise on wifi, only the actual video data (and keyboard/mouse controls I believe) goes over the wire)